# Txt file data into html text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Newbie here on javascript and CSS, and I wanna know if it's possible to extract data from a .txt file and transform it to text and print on the page.
I was searching through some old topics, and did find some similiar questions, and I tried to copy but didn't work hahha
Here it is what I did try:

HTML:

```
<div id="printed"></div>
```

Script:

```
var text_print = new XMLHttpRequest();
        text_print.open("GET", "folder/file.txt", true);
        text_print.send();
        text_print.onload = function (){
            console.log( text_print.responseText.slice(0, text_print.responseText.indexOf("\n")) ); };

    document.getElementById("printed").innerHTML=text_print;
```

The .txt file has only one line of text, btw.
Thank you.

Comment: Swap the `send` line and the `onload` one, to make sure the event listener is ready when the response comes back (especially if you're working locally). Then, insert your last line (`innerHTML`) inside your `onload` function. Because the response is only available in there. Also, don't set it to `text_print`, but `text_print.responseText.slice...`, because that is what you want to display in there. Also, make sure you're working on a server (http or https protocol, not `file:///`), and that both files (html and txt) are on the same domain. Otherwise, it won't work for security reasons.

Comment: No client cannot access files from the system. It can however get the text from any url

Comment: Is there a way to go around that? My project is not for web, I not gonna upload it, and depends that the .txt file read on local works. It cannot be done by other ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The right answer depends on what you're trying to do.

If you just want to to display the text (and that's it)

you can use the [embed](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) tool

```
<embed src="test.txt">
```

Where 'test.txt' is the name of your text file.

Note that you also need the path of the text file. So if test.txt is in the file directory below, you should use

```
<embed src="../test.txt">
```

or

```
<embed src="folder/file.txt"
```

in your case.

This is very simple to type. The disadvantage to this is that (as far as I'm aware) there is no way to apply styling to the text that gets displayed.

Comment: Yeah, I need to style the text hahaha  Thanks